# Dynamically generating a function tree in Python.

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-2.7

I want to do is something like this

```
def mult(x, y):
     return x * y

def add(x, y):
     return x + y

treeFunction = mult(2, add(x, y))

#outputs 10 (2 * ( 2 + 3 ))
print treeFunction(2, 3)
```

basically, is there a way during run-time to change add()'s return value by multiplying it by some value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *think* what you're asking for is a lambda function:

```
treeFunction = lambda x,y: mult(2, add(x, y))
```

Then just use it as:

```
treeFunction(2, 3)
```

**EDIT**

Have a read about [closures in python](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html). Definitely worth your time to learn.

Comment: There are a number of complex and general ways to do this, but I agree that for this particular example, the easiest solution is a lambda function.

Comment: The other way I interpreted this question was as asking for an interpreter for some domain-specific language. This code was easier to write.

Comment: is it hard to write `def treeFunction(x,y): return mult(2, add(x,y))` ? giving a name to a lambda is plain wrong

Comment: No, it isn't. In this case, yes, there is no difference, but what if it is in a function, and you want to assign the variable differing calls depending on a condition? Using anonymous functions isn't new. I doesn't clutter the namespace and allows you to generate function calls on the fly.

Comment: After sleeping on this and re-reading it all you have answered my question, but it didn't really help with my problem =P. My mistake. Thanks for the link to the closure stuff, very interesting.